# use comma-separated string with find

Tags: bash, find

I have a variable that contains a comma-separated list of directories I would want to find with the `find`command. I'd like to use them to do something similar to `find . -type d \( -name "Dir1" -o -name "Dir2" \)`.

I know I could go `for directory in ${VARIABLE//,/ }` and then call `find` for each directory separately, but is there a better, more direct way?

Comment: If `for directory in ${VARIABLE//,/ }` works, so will `find . -type d \( -name ${VARIABLE//,/ -o -name } \)`. A loop is gonna be more readable though.

Comment: Turn comma-delimited string into a pipe-delimited Regex:`find .  -type d -regextype awk -regex "./*($(printf %s "$str"|tr , \|))"` or with Bash's built-in substitution `find .  -type d -regextype awk -regex "./*(${str//,/|})"`.

Comment: In the `for directory` solution, you use the directories from the list as starting directories. In your attempt to do `-d name1 -o -dname 2`, you use your working dirctory as a starting directory and search matching direcrories somewhere down the directory tree. These are two very different things. IMO, you should first define what exactly you want to achieve, and then think of an algorithm.

Comment: `echo "-name '"${var//,/"'" -o -name "'"}"'"` gets you single quoting around your arr elements. Good luck to all.

Comment: @user1934428 the `for directory` iterates over the directory names but the actual command is `find` as well. In all cases the starting directory is the working directory.

Comment: @oguzismail your solution is exactly what I was looking for. If you post it as an answer I would gladly accept it (in the end I actually followed your advise and kept my loops)